# Try catch exception handling C++

Tags: c++, exception, ifstream

I have just started with exception handling in C++ using `try` and `catch` blocks. I have a text file with some data and I am reading this file using `ifstream` and `getline` as shown below,

```
ifstream file;
file.open("C:\\Test.txt", ios::in);
string line;
string firstLine;
if (getline(file, line, ' '))
{
    firstLine = line;
    getline(file, line);
}
```

I would like to know how to implement exception handling in case `file.open` fails to open the specified file because it does not exist in the given path, for example there is no `Test.txt` in `C:`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default iostreams do not throw exceptions. Instead they set some error flags. You can always test if the previous operation succeeded with a contextual conversion to bool:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("C:\\Test.txt", ios::in);
if (!file) {
    // do stuff when the file fails
} else {
    string line;
    string firstLine;
    if (getline(file, line, ' '))
    {
        firstLine = line;
        getline(file, line);
    }
}
```

You can turn on exceptions with the [`exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) member function. I find that more often than not, doing this doesn't help much because you can no longer do things like `while(getline(file, line))`: such an loop would only exit with an exception.

```
ifstream file;
file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
// now any operation that sets the failbit error flag on file throws

try {
    file.open("C:\\Test.txt", ios::in);
} catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
    // opening the file failed! do your stuffs here
}

// disable exceptions again as we use the boolean conversion interface 
file.exceptions(std::ios::goodbit);

string line;
string firstLine;
if (getline(file, line, ' '))
{
    firstLine = line;
    getline(file, line);
}
```

Most of the time, I don't think enabling exceptions on iostreams is worth the hassle. The API works better with them off.

Comment: `contextual conversion to bool` which means an `explicit bool()` in C++11 and an implicit conversion to `void*` interpreted as `bool` in c++03?

Comment: @rubenvb Well, the term didn't exist in C++03, but that's the equivalent, yeah.

Comment: @rubenvb Thank you. But how do I know which throws an exception and which doesn't?

Comment: @capricorn_heitus almost any operation on streams can fail. Usually you check their documentation and see if they can set any error flags. If they can and you enable exceptions, they will throw.

Comment: @rubenvb Turning on exceptions and doing stuff like that looks like a nightmare for me. I better go with simpler handling with `if` and `else` statements. Thank you for the simpler one :)

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure if you noticed, but you're replying to @rubenvb, not me :)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Oh, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

IOstreams give you the option of turning on exceptions for various state bits. The [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/) has a very clear example which is exactly what you were asking for.

Comment: I don't know about calling that site 'the STL reference', but +1 for pointing  out the ability to make it throw exceptions.

Comment: Hmm, confusing STL and iostreams (which are part of Standart C++ Library) is not a good thing. Edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well I meant it for two reasons.  The major one was that as far as I know, cplusplus.com is *not* maintained by the standards committee.  The other one was the very minor point that STL != C++ standard library.

Comment: @dtatulea Your discussion is out of my scope. Nevertheless, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends what you want to do if the file doesn't exist.

The code as it is at the moment (assuming this is `main`) will just exit the process.

However if this is a function call then you probably want to add exception handling around the call to this function.

E.g.

```
try
{
    OpenAndReadFile( std::string filename );
}
catch ( std::ifstream::failure e )
{
    // do soemthing else
}
catch ( OtherException e )
{
}
catch ( ... )
{
    // All others
}
```

This assumes that exception throwing is turned on for the `ifstream`.