# C++ Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault fstream

Tags: c++, csv, fstream

I'm getting the following error on my code, here are some lines from the code where the error is coming from:

```
int Datensatz = 0;
fstream fVerwaltung;
ifstream ifKunde;

struct kVerwaltung
{
int Nr;
string Name;
string Vorname;
string Ort;
int Alter;
};
kVerwaltung Kunde[100];

void Auslesen()
{
string line;
vector <string> v;
ifKunde.exceptions (ifstream::badbit); // Exceptions - Wenn die Datei nicht vorhanden ist
   try {
        ifKunde.open("DB.csv",ios::in);

        while (getline (ifKunde,line, ';')) {                   
        v.push_back(line);          
        }
        Datensatz = atoi(v[0].c_str()); // -> This is where the error comes from
        int j=2;
        for (int i=0; i<Datensatz; i++) {
            Kunde[i].Nr = atoi(v[j].c_str());
            Kunde[i].Name = v[j+1];
            Kunde[i].Vorname = v[j+2];
            Kunde[i].Ort = v[j+3];
            Kunde[i].Alter = atoi(v[j+4].c_str());
            j=j+5;
        }
        ifKunde.close();
    }
    catch (ifstream::failure e) {
            // Wenn die Datei nich vorhanden ist, wird die erstellt
            fVerwaltung.open("DB.csv", ios::out);
            fVerwaltung << Datensatz << ";" << endl;
            fVerwaltung.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
int wahl, i;
char auswahl;

bool beenden = false;
bool tHauptmenue = false;
Auslesen();
}
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is to open the DB.csv file, and if it doesn't exist, then the catch block should create one. But I get the SIGSEVG error everytime when the DB.csv file is not there, when it's there the program works fine. I've been googling for hours but couldn't find any solutions:( Thanks in advance.

Comment: Patient: _Doc, it hurts really badly when I poke my eye with a fork._ Doctor: _Stop poking your eye with a fork!_  I would expect `ifKunde.open()` to return some indication of success / failure, and upon seeing failure, I would expect you to not try to use the file that failed to open. From the docs: _If the function fails to open a file, the failbit state flag is set for the stream (which may throw ios_base::failure if that state flag was registered using member exceptions)._

Comment: @mah: It's also also possible that opening for writing succeeds, but trying to _write_ to an `ifstream` doesn't.

Comment: Of course, a debugger would help pinpointing _where_ the exception occurs.

Comment: Yeah the thing is that the open method usually creates the file if it's not there, and I've seen the same code work on another program, that's why I'm confused with the error. The problem occurs the first time when the program tries the atoi method, so in this case it's: `Datensatz = atoi(v[0].c_str());`

Comment: fstream::open sets failbit on failure, not badbit.

Comment: @lleshiart I also notice your exception handler performs an open / write / close without having any exception handling of its own, another potential source of the fault. This problem would probably be very simple to isolate by stepping through in a debugger, especially if it's easy to reproduce.

Comment: Yeah I tried the code with failbit, the program doesn't crash but it runs the catch block everytime, eventhough the DB.csv file is there. [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) is where I found the badbit from, there's also an example code there.

Comment: @mah The thing is that im Using Orwell-Dev C++ and I'm only getting the error and the line where it comes from, I'm not that good at debugging.

Comment: @lleshiart sometimes the line where the error comes from is enough to determine the failure; in this case you know it likely has to do with misuse of a file handler based on the description of what leads to the error. If that were not enough, you would need to step through code execution one line at a time, inspecting variables as you go -- this is the general reason debuggers are so helpful.

Comment: Have you tried checking that `v` actually contains anything before you try to get anything out of it?

Comment: Hi guys, I finally found out how to solve it, the problem was that my "while" loop was throwing an exception, that's why it was crashing the whole time. I found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650219/try-catch-exception-handling-c). Thanks a lot for your help!